# Attempting to create Primacy test in Python but stuck... please troubleshoot

Tags: python, numbers

```
from math import sqrt; from itertools import count, islice

n = input ("Enter a number: ")
notprime = ("Not a prime number.")

def isnotaprimenumber(n):
  if int(n) < 2: print (notprime)
  else:
    for number in islice(count(2), int(sqrt((int(n))-1)):
    if not (n%number == 0):
      print (notprime)


isnotaprimenumber(n)
```

I keep receiving a syntaxError related to the colon on

```
"for number in islice(count(2), int(sqrt((int(n))-1)):"
```

this line

Comment: If that is how your indentation actually looks, then that is the reason for the error.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing bracket in the for loop line - `for number in islice(count(2), int(sqrt((int(n))-1)):  #<-----one more closing bracket needed.` .

Also, the indentation of the `if` statement after that line is wrong.

And your logic is a bit wrong, in the inner `if` condition you should check for `(n%number == 0)`

The code should look like -

```
from math import sqrt; from itertools import count, islice

n = input ("Enter a number: ")
notprime = ("Not a prime number.")

def isnotaprimenumber(n):
  if int(n) < 2: print (notprime)
  else:
    for number in islice(count(2), int(sqrt((int(n))-1))):
      if (n%number == 0):
        print (notprime)
        return


isnotaprimenumber(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

you do not necessarily need islice: range is a generator. and better convert your n only once to an int:

```
from math import sqrt; 

n = int( input("Enter a number: ") )
notprime = "Not a prime number."


def isnotaprimenumber(n):
  if n < 2: 
      print(notprime)
  else:
      for number in range(2, int(sqrt(n)+1)):
          print(number)
          if (n%number == 0):
              print(notprime)
              return
      print('prime')

isnotaprimenumber(n)
```

Comment: Thank you for the constructive feedback... my code works now!

Comment: happy to help. and i hope this is just to learn python. if you seriously want to test for primality, there are much more efficient ways: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test .

Comment: and you could speed up your code by a) dividing 2 and odd numbers only or b) precalculating a list of primes and divide by those.